# Invariant Violation: Module JSTimers is not a registered callable module(calling callTimers).Issue due to device-info package in lerna setup

Tags: react-native, lerna, react-native-device-info

### React Native version:

0.64.0

### Steps To Reproduce

[Repo-code]https://github.com/rsoni5519/lerna-react-native

- Please use above link and follow the steps described in README.

### Expected Results

The App should work when we are clicking on Track buttons. it should console values for respective button events.
userAgent and screenSize should work for DeviceInfo and Dimensions.
[Module_JsTimer_Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSADc.jpg)
[steps to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs25p.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred  because of cyclic dependency of react-native pakcage.

Use this repository for solution [a link] (https://github.com/vishalkhoje/cyclicImportReactNative)!

1. Here problem is install **react-native-device-info** package as
   dependency into your root project not in your custom package.
2. In your custom package use react-native-device-info adn react-native as a peer dependancy.
   Ex. This is in your custom package.json file, important is version of package is same as root project package.json file.

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.64.1",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.64.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.1.2"
  }
```

This will solve your problem.

![Output screenshot:] [image]